# Changing audio output device while running Amazon Workspace Client

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, aws, client

Amazon WorkSpaces client uses a Teradici Virtual Audio Driver which is initialized with the system Sound settings when the connection is first opened. Whatever Sound device was selected in System Preferences when the connection was established will continue to be the sound device for as long as the session was open.

Is there a way to change audio output to AirPods or some other audio device when Amazon Workspace is running?